# Nodejs on GCE Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, proxy

I am using nodejs version 12, deployed on google cloud engine container

sometimes when I send http request to other microservice deployed also on google cloud engine I get this message

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

### Update

It's a normal docker container published on google cloud engine with normal configuration

here is my dockerFile configuration

```yaml
# ---- Base Node ----
FROM node:12-alpine AS base 
ARG env=dev
ENV NODE_ENV=${env}
# install node
RUN apk add --no-cache tini  
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Set tini as entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
# copy project file
COPY package.json .

# ---- Dependencies ----
FROM base AS dependencies
# install node packages
RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0
RUN npm install --only=production 
# copy production node_modules aside
RUN cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules
# install ALL node_modules, including 'devDependencies'
RUN npm install

#
# ---- Test ----
# run linters, setup and tests
FROM dependencies AS build
COPY . .
RUN  npm run lint
RUN  npm run build

#
# ---- Release ----
FROM base AS release
# copy production node_modules
COPY --from=dependencies /app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/build ./build
# copy app sources
COPY . .
# expose port and define CMD
EXPOSE 8080

CMD npm run start
```

Comment: This usually means you are trying to connect using TLS and the endpoint is not configured for TLS. Edit your question with details.

Comment: I updated it with more details an dockerfile configuration, what else details can be added ?

Comment: You are trying to connect to another system. Show the connection and the error and details on the other system.

Comment: the other system is also a docker container deployed with the same specs and file on google clound engine

Comment: If both system are configured the same, they are listening on port 8080. By convention port 8080 supports HTTP only and not HTTPS/TLS. You can support HTTPS/TLS but I do not see anything in your configuration that supports HTTPS/TLS. Show your code, the connection and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your Load Balancer is expecting a HTTPS connection instead of HTTP (that your container is providing at this point).

It's as @john-hanley mentions, but in this case, you would either configure your container backend to provide HTTPS connections or [configure](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple#load-balancer) your load balancer to "talk" with your backend using plain HTTP.

You would still be able to provide HTTPS connections to your end users, but this problem seems to be between your load balancer and your backend so far.